# Issue changing mysql password on Debian

Tags: linux, debian, mysql, database, database-administration

I installed mysql on my Debian server.  I couldn't get into the database because it kept saying I put in the wrong password so I looked on the internet and found that I could log onto mysql using the command sudo `mysql --defaults-file=/etc/mysql/debian.cnf` 
  From there I went typed `use mysql;`then `mysql> UPDATE user SET password=PASSWORD('password') WHERE user='root';`
  Which I know switched the password because I typed the command `select Host, User, Password from user;` And it showed the encrypted characters had changed for all three of the root user categories.
But I am still not able to login to mysql using `mysql -u root -p`

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to run `FLUSH PRIVILEGES`.

Though I'd recommend changing your password using `mysqladmin --defaults-file=/etc/mysql/debian.cnf password`